# 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: jquery, python, python-3.x, ajax, django

Имеется форма с двумя выпадающими списками и одной кнопкой. По нажатию на кнопку отправляются данные в виде json, на основе этих данных выполняется фильтрация, потом отфильтрованные данные возвращаются на клиент. Однако, вместо отфильтрованных данных, выводится ошибка `500 (Internal Server Error)`. В трейсбек выводиться следующее: `string indices must be integers`. Как исправить данную ошибку?

**Представление:**

```
 function GetSelectValue() {
                    var select_type = document.getElementById("type");
                    var type = select_type.value;
                    var select_net = document.getElementById("net");
                    var net = select_net.value;
                    var filter = JSON.stringify({type:type, net:net});
                    return filter
                }

                $(function () {
                    $("#btn1").click(function () {
                        var filter = GetSelectValue();
                        console.log(filter);
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            dataType: 'json',
                            url: '/map/filter/',
                            data: {
                                'filter': filter
                            },
                            success:
                                function (stations) {
                                    pointLayer.removeAll();
                                    draw_point_layer(stations);
                                },
                            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                console.log(error);
                            }
                        })
                    });
                });
<body>
<div name="infoDiv" id="infoDiv" class="esri-widget">
    <!--<b>Filter by geometry</b><br/><br/>-->
    <label for="net">Сеть:</label>
    <select id="net" class="options">
        <option value="INTERMAGNET">INTERMAGNET</option>
        <option value="IMAGE">IMAGE</option>
        <option value="EISCAT">EISCAT</option>
        <option value="MACCS">MACCS</option>
        <option value="CARISMA">CARISMA</option>
        <option value="CANMOS">CANMOS</option>
        <option value="AUTUMNX">AUTUMNX</option>
        <option value="USGS">USGS</option>
        <option value="AMN">AMN</option>
        <option value="DTU">DTU</option>
        <option value="ENIGMA">ENIGMA</option>
        <option value="EMMA/PLASMON">EMMA/PLASMON</option>
        <option value="Japan Meteorological Agency">Japan Meteorological Agency</option>
        <option value="GFZ">GFZ</option>
        <option value="Italian Magnetic Network">Italian Magnetic Network</option>
        <option value="Mid-continent Magnetoseismic Chain">Mid-continent Magnetoseismic Chain</option>
        <option value="Russian Arctic and Antarctic Magnetometer">Russian Arctic and Antarctic Magnetometer</option>
        <option value="Finnish Meteorological Institute">Finnish Meteorological Institute</option>
        <option value="Swedish Institute of Space Physics">Swedish Institute of Space Physics</option>
        <option value="BAS">BAS</option>
        <option value="Российско-украинский сегмент геомагнитных данных">Российско-украинский сегмент геомагнитных данных</option>
        <option value="all" selected>все</option>
    </select>
    <label for="type">Тип:</label>
    <select id="type" class="options">
        <option value="station">станция</option>
        <option value="observatory">обсерватория</option>
        <option value="all" selected>все</option>
    </select
    ><br/><br/>
    <button id="btn1" class="esri-button" id="clearFilter" type="button">
        Применить
    </button>
</div>
</body>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .models import Station
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core import serializers


def filter(request):
    if request.GET:
        filter = request.GET.get('filter')
        type = filter['type']
        if type == 'all':
            stations = serializers.serialize('json', Station.objects.all())
        else:
            stations = serializers.serialize('json', Station.objects.filter(type=type))
    return HttpResponse(stations, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Читайте логи сервера, в них обязательно будет написана причина ошибки

Comment: А трейсбек для кого придуман?

Answer (score 0):

Избавился от данной ошибки, применив метод `json.loads()`. Измененный views.py будет выглядеть следующим образом

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.views.generic import TemplateView
    from .models import Station
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.core import serializers
    import json


    def filter(request):
        if request.GET:
            filter = request.GET.get('filter')
            decoded_filter = json.loads(filter)
            type = decoded_filter["type"]
            if type == 'all':
                stations = serializers.serialize('json', Station.objects.all())
            else:
                stations = serializers.serialize('json', Station.objects.filter(type=type))
        return HttpResponse(stations, content_type='application/json')
```